# Why is git subtree missing commits?

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, yeoman, git-subtree

I just ran `git subtree split` on my master branch but the subtree(`dist` branch) is missing the last two commits that are on the `master` branch. I'm not sure what to do here. I haven't run into this before. It's always worked without issue.

Here's what my github network graph looks like(excluding `dist`):

[image: github network graph]

From the master branch I ran `git subtree split -P dist -b dist`.

If I run `git log` from the `dist` branch it shows the most recent commit is `6d1620a`. Where is `17c1f31` and `33dfc67`?

Anyone know what's going on here?

---

### More Details Specific to my Scenario

I am using the deployment method used by Yeoman generated projects. Basically meaning that I have an overall project folder within which there is a `dev`(or `app`) directory where all development is done and a `dist` directory which is where the project is built to(via gulp build process). So to deploy I just split the `dist` directory off into it's own branch and push that to the live server.

Which looks something like this:

```
gulp
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff dev
git subtree split -P dist -b dist
git push
```

Alternately `git subtree push -P dist origin dist` also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot the run the gulp build process. Because of this the new commit did not affect the `/dist` directory.

It makes sense that the commit wouldn't be passed on with a directory that was not affected by  it. But not knowing this behavior ahead of time really confused the situation for me.